# JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly using Maven wrapper for spring boot project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am on Windows 10.  I have defined my `JAVA_HOME` and path variables for both system and user as:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin
```

I have created a Spring Boot project with IntelliJ.

When I git bash into the project folder and try to execute:

```
./mvnw clean
```

I get this error:
`JAVA_HOME` is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute `C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-11.0.2/bin/bin/java`

Where in the world could that extra `/bin` be coming from?

Thank you for your help,
Marc

Answer (score 5):

Here you have not defined `JAVA_HOME` correctly.

You have to define the `JAVA_HOME` as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2` not the 
   `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin`.

Since maven uses your `JAVA_HOME` path and appends

that path with `bin/java` that's why there are `bin/bin/java` instead of `bin/java`

Answer (score 1):

Set Your JAVA_HOME

`JAVA_HOME =C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2`

instead of

`JAVA_HOME =C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin`

and update your `Path` by appending this line to your environment variable named `PATH` with `PATH=$JAVA_HOME\bin`

> Note :Java bin folder contains all executable, while java home means home directory of java.